# ¿Cómo comparar las sumas de dos periodos de tiempo, para retornar la variación porcentual entre ambos resultados, en una consulta SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero sumar la ventas de un mes concreto y compararlo con el mismo mes del año anterior. Es decir, Marzo 2018 con Marzo 2019 y que solo me muestre el porcentaje de la diferencia entre uno y otro.

Se hacer la suma de ventas pero no sacar una porcentaje entre las dos
[image: TABLA DE PRODUCTO CON PRECIO]

Como podéis ver en la imagen, solo me interesa sumar el total de un mes entero y compararlo con el mismo mes del año anterior.

Sé hacer la suma total del mes pero no se hacer la comparativa de del mismo mes del año anterior y que me un porcentaje:

Mi consulta actual:

```
SELECT COUNT(TOTAL)
FROM ALBVENTALIN 
WHERE FECHAENTREGA BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
```

Esta es la consulta si quiero saber el total de un mes.

Comment: Hola. Suigero que publiques el texto de los datos de entrada y la salida que esperas obtener con esos datos. También puede ayudar a mejorar tus posibilidades de obtener ayuda que publiques el código de la(s) consulta(s) que has intentado para resolver el problema. De otra forma, parece una solicitud de que alguien haga tu trabajo, más que una solicitud de ayuda. Un saludo y bienvenido a SO.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Estoy en una red restringida así que no puedo ver tu imagen, te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por el [tour] del sitio y leas la sección [ask].

Comment: Hola, gracias como he indicado anteriormente, se hacer la suma total del mes pero no se hacer la comparativa de del mismo mes del año anterior y que me un porcentaje

Comment: SELECT COUNT(TOTAL)FROM ALBVENTALIN 
WHERE FECHAENTREGA BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31' esta es la consulta si quiero saber el total de un mes

Comment: No pretendo que nadie haga esto, solo estoy preguntado como se hace una porcentaje porque no lo se de ahí que sea una consulta, si no lo haría yo mismo, pero agradezco tu opinión jach

Answer (score 0):

La base para hacerlo es tener ambos datos en la misma fila y para eso necesitamos usar funciones de agregado. Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo que puedes editar para completar la solución.

```
DECLARE @Fecha datetime = GETDATE(); --Parámetro

DECLARE @InicioMesActual   datetime,
        @FinMesActual      datetime,
        @InicioMesAnterior datetime,
        @FinMesAnterior    datetime;

SELECT @InicioMesActual = DATEADD( MM, DATEDIFF( MM, 0, @Fecha), 0),
       @FinMesActual    = DATEADD( MM, DATEDIFF( MM, 0, @Fecha) + 1, 0);
SELECT @InicioMesAnterior = DATEADD(YY, -1, @InicioMesActual),
       @FinMesAnterior    = DATEADD(YY, -1, @FinMesActual)

SELECT descripcion,
        SUM( CASE WHEN FechaEntrega >= @InicioMesActual AND FechaEntrega < @FinMesActual THEN Unid1 END) AS Unid1Actual,
        SUM( CASE WHEN FechaEntrega >= @InicioMesAnterior AND FechaEntrega < @FinMesAnterior THEN Unid1 END) AS Unid1Anterior,
        SUM( CASE WHEN FechaEntrega >= @InicioMesActual AND FechaEntrega < @FinMesActual THEN Total END) AS TotalActual,
        SUM( CASE WHEN FechaEntrega >= @InicioMesAnterior AND FechaEntrega < @FinMesAnterior THEN Total END) AS TotalAnterior
FROM MiTabla
WHERE (FechaEntrega >= @InicioMesActual   AND FechaEntrega < @FinMesActual)
   OR (FechaEntrega >= @InicioMesAnterior AND FechaEntrega < @FinMesAnterior)
GROUP BY descripcion;
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo Luis, le voy a dar una vuelta

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que intentas hacer es comparar la cantidad de ventas (ya sea la cantidad de ventas realizadas y/o la suma de ganancias de las ventas) entre un mes y otro anterior y obtener el %.

Antes de hacer funciones y/o SP como comentaron arriba, iría por algo mas sencillo pero menos bonito ni eficiente que es hacer un par se selects anidados... siempre luego puedes mejorarlo hasta donde necesites

```
SELECT comp.octubre2019, comp.octubre2018, 
    CONCAT((((comp.octubre2019 * 100) / comp.octubre2018) - 100), '%') as comparar
     FROM
    (SELECT 
        (select 150) as octubre2019, -- obtengo el valor para el mes mas nuevo
        (select 200) as octubre2018 -- obtengo el valor para el mes viejo a comparar
    ) as comp
```

y sale algo así:

```
octubre2019 octubre2018 comparar
----------- ----------- -------------
150         200         -25%
```

Con esto tb puedes comprar year to year (año completo contra año completo), year to day to year to day (del 1ro de enero al día actual contra igual periodo anterior). Estos son reportes bastantes comunes en finanzas y dashboards